# Java.net.MalformedURLException POST request

Tags: java, json, post, clojure

I am trying to send a POST Request to a gateway.

The URL I am trying to get to is http://pg.staging.weareswat.com/payment-reference/create

I am using insomnia to send the POST request

This is what I am trying to send:

```
{
    "supplier" : {
        "name":"Easypay"
    },
    "client-id": "some-id",
    "amount": 3.25,
    "currency": "EUR",
    "callback": "http://httpstat.us/200"
}
```

But for some reason the answer is a 500 server error with this body:

```
{
    "error": "Cannot JSON encode object of class: class java.net.MalformedURLException: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: "
}
```

The application I am trying to reach is written in clojure.

That only happens when I send the name "Easypay". When I send something like HiPay it works.

That logic is on the app side, and although I have access to the code, I didn't wrote it.

Can you help me? Thanks

Comment: You have not shown your url. The error states it has no protocol

Comment: Show the code you are using to send the POST request to the gateway. That might help in getting a solution. Also, specify what kind of request you are making? Is it an API call, and if so, what API are you calling?

Comment: The URL i am trying to get is this one http://pg.staging.weareswat.com/payment-reference/create
and it's a POST Request to that specific API using insomnia app

Comment: Any chance we can see the Clojure app code? I suspect that's where the problem is.

Comment: All of the URLs you've shown are valid. I suspect the app is looking up a URL based on the supplier, and that the configured URL for Easypay is invalid or something like that.